# Partition information from CMD

Tags: command-line, disk-partitioning

Is there any CMD command line that shows all partition letters. For example: C, D, E...

Can that command also show all the partition's information? Free space, used space, total space?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`diskpart`](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415/en-us)

```
c:\>diskpart

Microsoft DiskPart versión 6.1.7600
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Microsoft Corporation.
En el equipo: DV6470

DISKPART> list volume

  Núm Volumen Ltr  Etiqueta     Fs     Tipo        Tamaño   Estado     Info
  ----------- ---  -----------  -----  ----------  -------  ---------  --------
  Volumen 0     D                      DVD-ROM         0 B  Sin medio
  Volumen 1         Reservado   NTFS   Partición    100 MB  Correcto   Sistema
  Volumen 2     C   C           NTFS   Partición     38 GB  Correcto   Arranque
```

It accepts a script as command line parameter:

listvol.cmd:

```
echo list volume > listvol.scr
diskpart /s listvol.scr
del listvol.scr
```

Comment: How to use script?? I write diskpart /s list volume and gives me error. I use Win XP 64bit

Comment: @gedO - You need to create a text file with the commands. Answer edited.